# Processing AJAX request in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, pageload

I'm working with an AJAX button and label controls. When the user clicks the button, the data is updated in the label.

But after clicking the button, the Page_Load event occurs, and I don't want it, because all data is being initialized to default values.

How can I check in Page_Load event that it's an AJAX request?

I'm using UpdatePanel and ScriptManager as AJAX tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the page load check

```
  if (!Page.IsAsync)
  { 
  }
```